# How to install InertiaVue + tailwind in new laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I spent a lot of time to install InertiaVue and Tailwind on my new laravel 8. I have some experience with Vue.js.

I used this command to install inertia

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel nameofprojectt --prefer-dist
```

then I added this to the root template

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    @inertia
  </body>
</html>
```

then I ran this command

```
php artisan inertia:middleware
```

I registered the HandleInertiaRequests middleware in my App\Http\Kernel, as the last item in my web middleware group.

```
\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
```

And I ran Npm install than Npm run dev

But I got always got this error

> $page is undefined

Sorry if this question is to frequently about installation I am not really good on laravel. There is no clear installation how to install Laravel 8 (if yes I did not found it) with InertiaVue (does not say that need I install Vue separate or no) + Tailwind. (without jetstram).

If I use to install with jetstream everything is fine about Inertia.. But when I install without its not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to install them with JetStream.
You need to run these commands in this order:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install inertia
npm install && npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

For more information check: https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html

Edit:

- To install InertiaVue you should follow the server and client side installation on their website: https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup
- To install Tailwind:
  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

Comment: But I do not want use use Jetstream.  I would use Orchid Admin panel without jetsream.

Comment: I done this steps but always got this error: $page is undefined

Comment: Easiest way is to install Jetstream with either Livewire or Inertia. I use Inertia.  Note for Laravel 8 this install  uses Vue 3. For your needs, you can just ignore the Jetstream routes for login and registration, or change them to match your admin panel. The $page variable is sent by default from the Laravel Inertia middleware. It's like a global object with stuff you typically want to send to every page- errors, flash messages, current user etc.